# Reading a file (line by line) but the last line is empty in Haxe

Tags: haxe

How do I make sure that an eof exception won’t be thrown when I am reading the last empty line

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue:

[FileInput.readLine() fails if last line is empty (#5418)](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/5418)

Until that's resolved, I'd recommend to simply catch the exception rather than checking [`eof()`](https://api.haxe.org/sys/io/FileInput.html#eof) beforehand:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        var line = input.readLine();
        // ...
    }
} catch (e:haxe.io.Eof) {
    // stream has ended
}
```

Comment: @had Instead of writing "thank you!!!!!" you can also accept the given answer ;) Like this everyone will notice, that there is a solution to this question^^

Comment: `FileInput.eof()` tells if the EOF has been reached _in the past_.  Thus, for a last empty line, since no read has yet been attempted, it is necessary (at least for now) to check for a `haxe.io.Eof` exception.  By the way, this behavior used to be (loosely) documented somewhere during the Haxe 2.x days, but only a vague and non-authoritative [mention remains](http://old.haxe.org/doc/neko/fileio).